# How to get SQLite tabledata to ArrayList

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms

if have a small App created with Xamarin.Forms.

I have created the Table 'MyTable' in SQLLite in the Database Class.

TableModel:

```
public class MyTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string firstColumn { get; set; }
    public string secondtColumn { get; set; }
    public string thirdColumn { get; set; }
    public string fourthColumn { get; set; }
}
```

Datahelper:

```
public class Database
{
string dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MyTestDB.db");

public bool createDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);            
                connection.CreateTable<MyTable>();
                return true;               
        }
        catch (SQLite.SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.Info("SQLite Error!", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I have also created one method and a public List<> in the same Class

```
public void tableMyTable()
{
    try
    {
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
        connection.Table<MyTable>();

    }
    catch (SQLite.SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLite Error!", ex.Message);
        return;
    }
}

public List<Vokabeln> selectMyTable()
{
    try
    {
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);

        return connection.Table<MyTable>().ToList();
    }
    catch (SQLite.SQLiteException ex)
    {
        Log.Info("SQLite Error!", ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now I want to have the table data from a specific Column from MyTable to an ArrayList which has been created in a Content Page.

```
ArrayList question = new ArrayList();
```

How can I do this?

I have tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= db.selectTableVokabeln().Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (richtung == 1)
                                {
                                    question.Add(Mytable firstColumndata);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    question.Add(Mytable secondColumndata);
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: why?  You already have a `List<Vokabeln>`, why can't you just use that in your page?  What benefit does `ArrayList` provide?

Comment: I need some specific data from the table and therefore I want ot create new ArrayList with only data from one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList question = new ArrayList();
var data = selectMyTable();

foreach(var item in data)
{
  question.Add(item.SomeColumn);
}
```